# Closure is `FnOnce` because it moves the variable `________` out of its environment

Tags: rust

I've been having some issues with moving reference counted variables into closures which need to implement `FnMut`.

The following code works fine:

```
use std::rc::Rc;

fn main() {
    let callback;

    let data: Rc<Vec<f32>> = Rc::new(Vec::new());

    {
        let data = data.clone();

        callback = move || {
            data.iter().for_each(|v| println!("{}", v));
        };

        consumer(callback);
    }
}

fn consumer<D>(callback: D)
where
    D: FnMut(),
{
}
```

If I change the closure to:

```
callback = move || {
    data;
};
```

The compiler produces the error:

```
  --> src/test1.rs:11:20
   |
11 |         callback = move || {
   |                    ^^^^^^^ this closure implements `FnOnce`, not `FnMut`
12 |             data;
   |             ---- closure is `FnOnce` because it moves the variable `data` out of its environment
...
15 |         consumer(callback);
   |         -------- the requirement to implement `FnMut` derives from here
```

This example works:

```
callback = move || {
    let x = data[0];
    println!("{}", x);
};
```

This example does not:

```
callback = move || {
    let x = data;
    println!("{}", x[0]);
};
```

With `let data: Arc<Mutex<Vec<f32>>> = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Vec::new()));`, this works:

```
callback = move || {
    let x = data.lock().unwrap();
};
```

This does not:

```
callback = move || {
    let x = data;
};
```

What is the reasoning behind this?

Comment: Why are you doing `let audio_buffer = audio_buffer;` to begin with? I think it will work if you drop that and use the outer `audio_buffer` normally

Comment: Just putting a line `audio_buffer;` causes the problem, the only purpose of that line is to reference the variable for the demonstration.

Comment: But how are you actually using `audio_buffer`? If you call something that consumes the outer value, you'll get this error. If you call something that just uses a reference to the outer value, I believe it will work. `let audio_buffer = audio_buffer;` means _move_ the value from the out scope to the scope of one specific function call, which means the function can only be called once, or else the same value would be moved multiple times.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The following code works fine:
>
> ```
> let data: Rc<Vec<f32>> = Rc::new(Vec::new());
> {
>     let data = data.clone();
>     callback = move || {
>         data.iter().for_each(|v| println!("{}", v));
>     };
> ```

First, when the closure is constructed, `data` is *moved* into it, because the closure is declared as `move ||`. That's why you need to clone beforehand if you want to use `data` again outside the closure

Then later, when the closure is *called,* [`iter()` is a method that takes `&self`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.iter), so `data` is not moved out by the method call; it is *borrowed*, and the closure still owns it. Thus, the closure can be called as many times as you want — it automatically implements `Fn` and not just `FnOnce`.

> ```
> callback = move || {
>     data;
> };
> ```

> ```
> callback = move || {
>     let x = data;
>     println!("{}", x[0]);
> };
> ```

Here, when the closure is called, `data` is moved (used by value, not by reference). In the first case, it is immediately dropped; in the second it is moved into the local variable `x`.

If a value is moved out of a closure, then the closure only implements `FnOnce`, and can only be called once, because if the closure were called a second time, it wouldn't have that value to use any more.

**In general, any plain mention of a variable name is a move.** Everything else is a specific exception:

- If the value implements the `Copy` trait then it can be a copy instead of a move, which means the original stays valid. (Does not apply here, since `Rc` does not implement `Copy`.)
- If you call a method such as `.iter()` or `.lock()`, the method can take `&self` or `&mut self`; Rust automatically takes a reference as if you had written `(&data).iter()` instead.
- `println!` is a macro which implicitly takes references to its arguments, for convenience.

If you write `&data;` or `let x = &data;` instead, then you will have created a reference, which does not move the original value.

Comment: No, even when nothing is in `// some stuff` the same error occurs.

Comment: @sergmister OK. Could you edit your question to provide a complete, compilable sample (preferably one that will work in the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/))? It's much easier to be precise when we can see the compilation errors and explore the effects of changes.

Comment: Okay, I will do that

Comment: "Here, iter() is a method that takes &self. Thus, data is not moved out/consumed by the method call." Then why is not possible to use data after the closure if it is not consumed?

Comment: @sergmister It's moved _into_ the closure because you wrote `move ||`. Without `move`, it would be borrowed instead. I've edited my answer to describe this some more.

Answer (score 2):

To cover the same topic from a slightly different angle than the accepted answer - there are two concepts that are related but distinct:

1. `move` ensures that the `data` value is moved into the closure, and does not outlive the closure.
2. the above is independent of whether merely **calling** the closure needs to consume `data`.

In case of `move || data.lock().unwrap()`, your closure's call implementation takes `&self`, and can be called multiple times, destroying `data` only when the closure is dropped.

In case of `move || data`, the closure's call implementation takes `self` and immediately consumes data (and the rest of the closure), which is why it can be called only once, and will drop `data` by the time it returns.

The case in #2, the body of the closure consuming the data (`move || data` or just `|| data`) implies that the closure takes ownership of the captured value. The reverse doesn't apply: the mere fact that you used `move` to force the closure to take over the ownership of the value doesn't automatically mean that the call will consume the value. But if you wish, you can always force that by doing something like `drop(data)` in the closure body, which will make your closure `FnOnce`.